# The shutdown function in the main php script is not executing when I call exit() from included script

Tags: php

I have a `main.php` script which include another script named `inc.php`. When I call `exit` function from the `inc.php`, the `main.php` dies without executing the function registered as a shutdown function. Like:

**main.php**

```
<?php
echo "A\n";
include 'inc.php';
function whenEnd(){
    echo " this won't be echoed ";
}
register_shutdown_function ('whenEnd');
?>
```

**inc.php**

```
<?php
echo "B\n";
exit;
?>
```

running `main.php` will return

```
A
B
```

But I was expecting

```
A
B
this won't be echoed
```

what is wrong?

Comment: please change the line `echo " this won't be echoed ";`  to  `echo " this need to be echoed before die "; ` as it is confusing some answer-er

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function must be registered before exit.

```
<?php
echo "A\n";
function final(){
echo " this won't be echoed ";
}
register_shutdown_function ('final');
include 'inc.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are two problems in your Code

1. exit keyword will exit the PHP Execute.
2. final is a keyword is PHP, which could not be used as a function name.

With your expected out

```
A
B
this won't be echoed
```

Try out the code below:

for index.php

```
<?php
echo "A\n";
function test(){
echo " this won't be echoed ";
}
include 'inc.php';
register_shutdown_function ('test');
exit;
?>
```

for inc.php

```
<?php
echo "B\n";
?>
```

Comment: you might have misunderstood the post. He wants to exit from `inc.php` script and after that the code must trigger the registered shutdown function before exit.

Comment: Based on the output, here the script is.  
In PHP, that is not necessary to use exit to back to the main thread (index.php) after complete executing the required file. That is why i assume that he want to stop the whole thread at the end of index.php.